# Is using a argument=False a good practice?

Tags: python-3.x

I am defining a function that does two things. Grabing all items in one folder and filtering. Then, return the full address or only the file name.

```
def grab_all_images(address, full_address=False):

    FORMAT_LST = ('.svg', '.jpg', '.jpeg', '.png', '.jfif')
    lst_files = os.listdir(address)
    if not full_address:
        lst_files = [
            el for el in lst_files if os.path.splitext(el)[1].lower() in FORMAT_LST
            ]
    else:
        lst_files = [
            address + '\\' + el for el in lst_files if os.path.splitext(el)[1].lower() in FORMAT_LST
            ]

    return lst_files
```

Is the default argument full_adress=False a Pythonic thing? I have never seen it. I want to have it as a default argument to ensure backwards compatibility.

Comment: Seems fine to me.

Comment: Convention would typically be `full_address=None`. `None` is a singleton so it makes for a good sentinel value. That being said, in this context it seems fine.

Comment: If you take a look at `dataclasses.dataclass` in the standard library, it has a lot of optional boolean parameters (some of which have `True` as their default, some of which have `False` as their default). I think it's a fairly common pattern to have boolean defaults. https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.dataclass

Comment: @Axe319 `False` is a singleton as well, and has the correct type.

Comment: In the code sample's context, yes, which is why I included the last sentence. However, the title makes it seem like it's asking as a generalized default argument. Where `None` is common enough to have a specialized `Optional` type hint in the standard library.

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately I have to answer as I don't have enough reputation points to comment.
But to answer your question, yes this is absolutely fine to add to your code.

As others have mentioned, however, it would probably be best to replace it with `full_address=None` if you're expecting an actual address to be passed through
(i.e as a string).

Setting the default to a boolean value makes it seem like full_address is expecting a boolean value, although this is absolutely fine if it is.

Comment: Why would you prefer `None` to empty string (`''`)? For readability, I prefer to have the default value the same type as expected type. Objects are a different story, and there I use `None`.

Comment: @bfris, it is true that an empty string may be more readable, however, I'm thinking about other data types or Objects that might be included. OP could have an Address class (which acts as a full address) that might be passed through instead of a string. But that should be fine if only strings are expected through

Comment: @bfris Why would anyone prefer anything over `False`? Looking at how it's used by the function, it's clearly a boolean flag.

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode. You are right. I am embarrassed to admit I didn't read the code carefully enough to see that `full_address` is clearly implicitly boolean. This answer may have made a similar mistake as I did and presumed `full_address` is a string. And for a string data type, empty string would be my preferred default value.